# KOMA-Script: How to put text dirctly under headsepline?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, headline

How can I put some centered text directly under the headsepline?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, includehead, 
showframe=false
headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[ headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some stuff here... \\ Some stuff there...}
%\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\centering Text directly under headsepline}
\begin{document}
Content...
\end{document}
```

Comment: The headsepline separates head from body, hence the name. Use `\chead{wombat\\capybara\\\hrule \\ Mara}`  instead (untested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also declare new layer:

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  headsep,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering
    Text directly under headsepline}}
]{headseplayer}
```

and add this layer to the pagestyle:

```
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{headseplayer}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,includeheadfoot,
  %showframe,
  headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[ headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some stuff here... \\
       Some stuff there}%

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  headsep,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering
    Text directly under headsepline}}
]{headseplayer}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{headseplayer}
\begin{document}
Content...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: You have to ensure that the length `\headsep` is big enough. Maybe you have to set geometry option `headsep` to an appropriate value.

Comment: How can I set that Layer only at the first (or second) page?

Comment: It depends on what you want do. If you know that the text should only appear at the second page: `contents={\ifnum\value{page}=2 ... \fi}`. But you can also remove layers from a page style using `\RemoveLayersFromPagestyle{<pagestyle>}{<layer list>}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm,
 includefoot, includehead,
 showframe=false, %<--- comma was missing
 headheight=2\baselineskip,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[ headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{Some stuff here... \\
       Some stuff there}%
\ohead{\makebox[\textwidth]{%       
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-1.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \normalfont Text directly under headsepline}}}

\begin{document}
Content...
\end{document}
```

[image]